# Docker - ASP.NET Core: Failed to build docker image in Visual studio 2019

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I have an ASP.NET Core project which I want to build as docker image but it fails.

My project directory:

-myproject

--Blazor.Server

---Blazor.Server.csproj

---dockerfile

--Blazor.Shared

---Blazor.Shared.csproj

My dockerfile:

[image: My dockerfile]

When I build this dockerfile, I get the error below:

[image: Error]

I will be very thankful for any advise to solve this issue.

Comment: It's because the build context is not in the project root folder but it's at the folder which dockerfile stand at. Try to move dockerfile into --dockerfile instead of ---dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker engine didn't find resources through your path during building.

You should change your project structure as follows:

```
myproject
├─Blazor.Server
│  └─Blazor.Server.csproj
├─dockerfile
└─Blazor.Shared
   └─Blazor.Shared.csproj
```